# Why is this code outside my "using" statement unreachable?

Tags: c#

If an exception is thrown in a using statement, it should immediately call the `finally` block, and dispose of the object. So the rest of the `try` block should not execute, right?

```
 public static async Task<bool> AddCharName(string id, string name)
        {
            using (var dbConn = new DbConn())
            {
                await dbConn.Connection.OpenAsync();

                command = "UPDATE user SET name = @name WHERE name IS NULL AND id = @id";

                using (MySqlCommand update = dbConn.Connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    update.CommandText = command;
                    update.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
                    update.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id;
                    await update.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

In my example, the `return false` is giving the "Unreachable code detected" warning. Am I correct to dismiss this as a mistake? Like I am thinking if an error is thrown in the `using (MySqlCommand upd...` well then it should return false right?

Comment: You don't have a `try` block.

Comment: `using` is really a `try finally` block, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed `using` is syntactical sugar for try-finally but as there is no catch block. In other words you have:

```
MySqlCommand update = dbConn.Connection.CreateCommand();
try
{
    update.CommandText = command;
    update.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
    update.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id;
    await update.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    return true;
}
finally
{
    update.Dispose();
}
```

Note how there is no `catch`, therefore your code either:

1. Reaches `return true;` and returns there, or
2. throws an exception. The `finally` block gets executed disposing the object, then the exception immediately bubbles up to the caller (crashing if there is no handler).

In neither case does execution go past your `return true;` statement. The same is of course true with the outer `using` block as well.

---

Now, what you most likely want to do is `catch` exceptions that happen. The quick and dirty way would be to wrap everything in a try-catch, though depending on the application you may want to be more granular about where you catch what and how:

```
try
{
    using (var dbConn = new DbConn())
    {
        await dbConn.Connection.OpenAsync();

        command = "UPDATE user SET name = @name WHERE name IS NULL AND id = @id";

        using (MySqlCommand update = dbConn.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            update.CommandText = command;
            update.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
            update.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id;
            await update.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
catch (MySqlException)
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Quite simple really...

It **always** returns from

```
return true;
```

It never has the chance to get to

```
return false;
```

This is the case of the compiler knows best

**Update**

> Are you sure? So if an exception occurs in the using statement, before
>   return true it will still return true?

Although `using` implements *try finally*, it still throws the original exception, and hence still never gets to the `return false;` (no matter what happens)

Comment: Are you sure? So if an exception occurs in the using statement, before `return true` it will still return true?

Comment: @Bureto No, it'll just crash as your exception will be unhandled.

Answer (score 3):

Code Unreachable because you already has a `return true` above.

use `try catch`

```
try
            {
                using (var dbConn = new DbConn())
                {
                    await dbConn.Connection.OpenAsync();

                    command = "UPDATE user SET name = @name WHERE name IS NULL AND id = @id";

                    using (MySqlCommand update = dbConn.Connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        update.CommandText = command;
                        update.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
                        update.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id;
                        await update.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

It will go into the finally block, but you will still have the exception being thrown after the finally has finished, therefore it will not be able to return a value in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing because In case there is exception in using block it will first dispose itself and then it comes to catch block and your `return false;` become unreachable. What i suggest is keep the value in a variable.